# Invoking "Icicles"

Tags: ido, icicles

I'm trying to get started using [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles), but I'm wondering if `ido` is interfering with functionality. So far:

1. I installed Icicles from the repo and added

   ```
   (require 'icicles)
   ```

   to `init.el`.
2. I used `M-x` `customize` to turn off `ido`, resulting in

   ```
   '(ido-mode nil nil (ido))
   ```

   in the `custom-set-variables` section of `init.el`.
3. Restarted Emacs.

Now, running `C-h c` `C-x C-f` gives me the result of

> `C-x C-f` runs the command `ido-find-file`

However, the EmacsWiki page on Icicles says this command should have been automatically remapped to `icicle-file`. There are some other functions that also don't seem to be working. By contrast, though, `C-h c` `M-x` results in

> `M-x` runs the command `icicle-execute-extended-command`

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try starting from `emacs -Q` and loading Icicles. If `C-x C-f` is bound to `ido-find-file` then you clearly have not removed Ido from the equation. And maybe try using the Customize UI, instead of fiddling with code in your init file.

Comment: And I don't think you found anything in the Icicles doc (including on Emacs Wiki) about `ido-find-file` being remapped to `icicle-file`.

Comment: [This](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_Ido_and_IswitchB) is the Icicles doc page that speaks about Ido.

Comment: And [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_Icompletion) is the Icicles doc page about Icomplete (`icomplete-mode`), if you want some Ido-like behavior with Icicles.

Comment: I restarted with `emacs -Q` and turned on `icy-mode` and found that `C-x C-f` was now bound to `icicle-file` so I guess `ido` is still somehow not fully disabled, as you suspected. [Here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input)'s the page I was referencing, which contains this: "...command `find-file`, is by default remapped in Icicle mode to multi-command `icicle-file`. Remapping means that any keys, such as `C-x C-f`, that would normally be bound to `find-file` are instead bound to `icicle-file` when you are in Icicle mode."

Comment: Yes, `find-file` is remapped to `icicle-file`, which means that any keys that would normally be bound to the former are bound to the latter. By default in Emacs, `C-x C-f` is bound to `find-file`. But of course if you do something that binds `C-x C-f` to something else then remapping `find-file` will have no effect on that key. The command remapping affects only the keys that `file-file` is bound to.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with `emacs -Q` and manually entering `icicle-mode` solved the problem, so it turned out that `ido` was still active despite my attempts to disable it through the `customize` interface.

On a newbie hunch I opened my init.el, added

`(ido-mode nil)`

and restarted emacs. This worked. Now `C-x C-f` is bound to `icicle-file` and other functionality seems normal.

Comment: That sounds right. The best way to turn off something like Ido (or Icicles) is to use its mode command: `ido-mode` for Ido, `icicle-mode` for Icicles.