# Invoking "dired+"

Tags: dired

This is superficially similar to a question I asked [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3200/invoking-icicles) but I think the answer might be different.

I'm trying to use `dired+` and `highlight` but I don't seem to be getting the full functionality. When I do `C-x d` the resulting buffer is a regular `dired` buffer, without the dired+ formatting I've seen in various screenshots (where, for instance, autofile bookmarks are highlighted). `C-h c C-x d` tells me that the command being run is `dired`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363695/emacs-how-to-install-and-use-dired) 1.5-year-old discussion at Stack Overflow suggests adding the following keybinding to `init.el`:

```
(define-key ctl-x-map   "d" 'diredp-dired-files)
(define-key ctl-x-4-map "d" 'diredp-dired-files-other-window)
```

But this results in

> Symbol's function definition is void

when I invoke `C-x d` after evaluation. Perhaps the name of these functions has changed since that answer was given, but looking at the completion possibilities when I try `M-x diredp-' I'm not sure where to turn.

Comment: Did you require `dired+`? (Ie `(require 'dired+)`.) I forget that sometimes, and it would give you a similar error message.

Comment: Yes, I've got that (though I have also forgotten it at times!). I also have `(require 'dired-x)` and `(require 'highlight)`.

Comment: Can you `C-h f diredp-dired-files`?  If `describe-function` can't find it, it means you either don't have it loaded correctly or you have the wrong function name.  If it can find it, it would suggest the problem is in your keybinding.

Comment: I tried this, and the system can't find `diredp-dired-files`. However, as you say, I'm not sure if this is a load problem or if that's no longer the name of the function. When I do `C-h f diredp-` and TAB for completion, I get a huge list of `diredp` commands.

Comment: Ah, turns out that, if you look in the [source code](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/dired%2b.el), `diredp-dired-files` and `diredp-dired-files-other-window` were removed quite recently (9/14/2014).

Comment: Following up: I don't used `dired+`, but in glancing through the source code, I think the commands are now named `diredp-dired-for-files` and `diredp-dired-for-files-other-window`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Bookmark highlighting, including highlighting of autofile bookmarks, is provided by [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus), not by [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/DiredPlus).
2. The [old S.O. post you cite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363695/emacs-how-to-install-and-use-dired) was up-to-date when it was written. Today, you just use command `dired`. It is advised, and functions it calls are modified, to do what the **Dired+** doc says.
3. You do not need to explicitly `require` `dired-x.el` - **Dired+** does that.
4. All the information you need should be in the `dired+.el` file header.  If something is missing, please send me an email about it. Thx.

Comment: In my `dired` buffers, a .txt file looked just the same as a directory folder. After some fiddling, I realized that it was the fault of the zenburn theme I was using, which color-scheme canceled the work that dired+ was doing. Other themes represent things more correctly. Wow, that took me a long time to figure out. Thank you for your help. Onward and upward ...

Comment: Hm. Just which faces does that theme trample on, which affect Dired(+)?

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser. I went back to zenburn to answer your question more exactly, and suddenly everything is rainbows in here---it looks great. What just happened? I restarted emacs again, and am back to where I started. I'll look into this a little more today and see if I have anything cogent to say about it later on. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Put your cursor on highlighted text and hit `C-u C-x =`, to see what face(s) are present at that position.  That will tell you something about what is going on.  Perhaps that theme alters some faces that are used by Dired(+), or that are inherited by faces that are used by Dired(+). You can also use `M-x list-faces-display` to see the currently available faces.

Comment: I restarted emacs with the `-Q` switch, and enabled `dired+`, `bookmark+` and `highlight` from there--everything works perfectly. So I think it must be a conflict with some other package I have loaded? Is 'trial and error' the only way to troubleshoot that kind of thing? If so, I'll get started.

Comment: No, not trial and error. **Recursively bisect your init file.** Use command `comment-region` to comment out 1/2 of it, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16,... till you find the problematic code. (Use `C-u` with `comment-region` to uncomment code.) If narrowing it down shows some library is the culprit, you can do the same thing on (a copy of) that library code: bisect until you find the offending part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18504/discussion-between-steven-arntson-and-drew).